# Is it possible to use Oracle to get a rollup count of employees at each level?

Tags: oracle, hierarchical-data

Suppose you have a standard org hierarchy table in Oracle. For simplicity sake, assume that you have a column in that Org table that shows how many employees are DIRECTLY assigned to that org.

```
create table org (
    org_id NUMBER(5),
    parent_org_id NUMBER(5),
    emp_count NUMBER (5)
);

insert into org values (1, NULL, 200);
insert into org values (2, 1, 50);
insert into org values (3, 1, 100);
insert into org values (4, 2, 100);
```

Is it possible to get a result set that looks like this:

```
OrgID, Count
1, 450
2, 150
3, 100
4, 100
```

That is, there are not 450 people DIRECTLY assigned to OrgId1, but when you add up everyone in OrgID1 and BELOW, there are 350 people directly or indirectly assigned. Again, with OrgId2, there are 50 assigned directly + the 100 assigned under it (in Org 4).

Simple idea right? Is this kind of query possible in Oracle?

Comment: This is certainly possible in Oracle. Would you be prepared to self-flag for moderator migration to [dba.se](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) and create yourself an account there? I think this is advanced enough to be a better fit over there and will get answered quickly.

Comment: hint: `select connect_by_root(org_id) as org_id, emp_count from org connect by parent_org_id=(prior org_id)`

Comment: @JackDouglas, perfect. Add it as an answer :)

Comment: Any thoughts on my suggestion of a migration? I'd love to have both this question and its poster over there :-) Anyway, answer posted...

Comment: Ditto, would be a good fit for dba.se

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with a hierarchical query the 'wrong' way round - no `start with` clause means every row is a start point, then traverse the tree to each leaf and group up the results by each start point:

```
select org_id, sum(emp_count) as emp_count
from ( select connect_by_root(org_id) as org_id, emp_count
       from org 
       connect by parent_org_id=(prior org_id) )
group by org_id;

/*
ORG_ID                 EMP_COUNT             
---------------------- ----------------------
1                      450                  
2                      150                  
4                      100                  
3                      100                  
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have oracle avaliable to test this, but can you do something like the following:

```
select OrgID
     , count(*) + (select count(*) from org orgSub where org.orgID = orgSub.parentOrgId) total
  from org
group by OrgID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CONNECT_BY_ROOT in a hierarchical query to get the root organization of each row.  Once the root org is known on each row, you can add it to a rollup calculation:

```
create table org (
    org_id NUMBER(5),
    parent_org_id NUMBER(5),
    emp_count NUMBER (5)
);

insert into org values (1, NULL, 200);
insert into org values (2, 1, 50);
insert into org values (3, 1, 100);

select
    root_org_id,
    org_id,
    sum(emp_count)
from (
    select
        CONNECT_BY_ROOT org_id as root_org_id,
        org_id,
        emp_count
    from
        org
    start with
        parent_org_id is null
    connect by
        parent_org_id = prior org_id
)
group by rollup (root_org_id, org_id);
```

This produces:

```
ROOT_ORG_ID,ORG_ID,SUM(EMP_COUNT)
1,1,200
1,2,50
1,3,100
1,,350
,,350
```

The row with a null org_id would be a rollup for the root org.  The final row with null root_org_id and org_id is the grand total.

Comment: Probably my question was a little too vague. See the updates I made. Basically, I need to find the count at EACH level, not just the root.